# Convert Windows API call to 64-bit in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, api, excel, winapi

I'm using this Windows API call in 32-bit Excel, and it's working fine:

```
Declare Function WNetGetConnection Lib "MPR.DLL" _
    Alias "WNetGetConnectionA" ( _
        ByVal lpszLocalName As String, _
        ByVal lpszRemoteName As String, _
        lSize As Long) As Long
```

I'm told that a small percentage of our corporate users will soon be going to 64-bit Excel. I don't have access to 64-bit Excel and I haven't been able to find any coworkers nearby who do.

According to this file, if I'm reading it correctly...

http://www.cadsharp.com/docs/Win32API_PtrSafe.txt

...this is the correct syntax of that function for 64-bit Excel:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function WNetGetConnection Lib "MPR.DLL" _
    Alias "WNetGetConnectionA" ( _
        ByVal lpszLocalName As String, _
        ByVal lpszRemoteName As String, _
        lSize As Long) As Long
```

But is that correct? The only difference is adding PtrSafe. Should it point to a different, 64-bit version of MPR.DLL? Also, should lSize be LongLong rather than Long?

Comment: Please don't ask us to do your testing for you. Install 64 bit Excel yourself.

Comment: "Testing" is not a reliable method of determining API declarations in Excel. Firstly, Excel does stack correction after API calls: that hides declaration errors: in this case it would hide an error in the bit length of the return value. Secondly, testing the API requires a known valid testing framework, which is almost never the case. And thirdly - some of the API has optional terms which are almost never used, leading to hidden errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But is that correct?

Yes. But don't take my word for it. Get a copy of Office and test it.

> The only difference is adding PtrSafe. Should it point to a different, 64-bit version of MPR.DLL?

No. Windows chooses the appropriate DLL for the bitness of your process.  For standard WinAPI components, you should only use the DLL name, and never a full path.  Windows will pick the correct one.

> Also, should lSize be LongLong rather than Long?

It should be `ByRef Long`.  The [`WNetGetConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385453.aspx) documentation shows the function prototype:

```
DWORD WNetGetConnection(
  _In_    LPCTSTR lpLocalName,
  _Out_   LPTSTR  lpRemoteName,
  _Inout_ LPDWORD lpnLength
);
```

[`DWORD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751.aspx) is a 32 bit unsigned integer.<sup>1</sup> `LPDWORD` is a pointer to a `DWORD`, which in VB(6/A) is `ByRef lpnLength As Long`.

As a bonus:

- In the Windows API `LONG` is also 32 bit. This does not change whether you're running 32 or 64 bit. (`sizeof(DWORD) == sizeof(LONG) == sizeof(INT)`)
- [VBA Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263420.aspx)

---

*<sup>1</sup>Fun Fact: VBA doesn't have unsigned integer types, since VB6 didn't have them. VB6 came out in '98.*

*A brand-new never-before-used single user license for Office 2016 is running about $150 as of 7-Oct-15.  It's also available through the MSDN subscription programs.  It's also available at many fine retailers. (I'm intentionally not posting links.)*